# VS Code 1.75 can't install any extensions: "'github.vscode-pull-request-github' wants API proposal 'commentsResolvedState'"

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have used VS Code for a long time and it always worked fine. Suddenly today vs code does not recognize file extensions. Whether .js or .css it marks them always as plain text file.

Then I saw that all my extensions somehow are not installed anymore and when I try to install them again, it gives an error:

```
2023-02-14 12:48:17.453 [info] Electron sandbox mode is enabled!
2023-02-14 12:48:17.489 [warning] Via 'product.json#extensionEnabledApiProposals' extension 'github.vscode-pull-request-github' wants API proposal 'commentsResolvedState' but that proposal DOES NOT EXIST. Likely, the proposal has been finalized (check 'vscode.d.ts') or was abandoned.
2023-02-14 12:48:18.714 [error] Error scanning installed extensions:
2023-02-14 12:48:18.715 [error] SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.factory (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/kilia/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:741:99212)
2023-02-14 12:48:19.980 [error] SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.factory (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/kilia/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:88:93520)
...
```

I tried to remove all extensions folders from `C:\Users\kilia\.vscode\extensions` and install it after removing, but it did not work.

Comment: Installing the vs code version from nov 2022 worked for me. https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_74

Comment: Were you on the most recent build before: v1.75.1?  And did you also delete `extensions.json` from that extensions location?

Comment: @Mark I am sorry, I can't tell which version I had. It should be an older one, because I installed vs code1 or 2 years ago. And yes, I deleted extensions.json and it did not work

Comment: Okay, I have seen it recommended by the vscode team member responsible for extension loading to delete `extensions.json` as a fix.  It seems to work for some people.  There have been a lot of reported issues on this recently.  Hopefully it gets sorted soon.

Comment: Same question but got deleted by the asker: [How to fix VS code extension install error?](/q/75453481/11107541)

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been reported on GitHub and a fix has been verified.

I'm assuming you're on VS Code v1.75.1 (the latest version at the time of this writing).

See this issue in the [`microsoft/vscode-pull-request-github`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-pull-request-github) repo: [Unknown error message help -extension 'github.vscode-pull-request-github' wants API proposal 'commentsResolvedState' but that proposal DOES NOT EXIST #4518](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-pull-request-github/issues/4518)

> Found the issue for the GitHub Pull Requests extension. The fix will be available in the next VS Code insiders build. Unfortunately, I can't just update the extension to resolve this issue in the stable build - [@alexr00](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-pull-request-github/issues/4518#issuecomment-1429931682)

> Note that this warning will not impact the functionality of this extension at all. - [@alexr00](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-pull-request-github/issues/4518#issuecomment-1429933009)

I'm assuming the issue they're referring to is this one: [After updating vscode insiders, getting wants API proposal 'commentsResolvedState' with Github Extension #4425](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-pull-request-github/issues/4425).

[Other people in that thread also experience the side effect of not being able to install extensions due to this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-pull-request-github/issues/4518#issuecomment-1435070275).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to temporarily fix by using the insider build of vsCode
[VScode Insider download page](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/). This beta version already has the fix and works fine now. Once they update the normal version you can go back. Once installed you can use `code-insiders .` To run the insider build for a directory and install any extensions.

Comment: How _much_ does this really add on top of my answer? The quoted section in my answer already says that the issue is fixed in the insiders build.