# I am unable to install any extensions or code spaces on visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I first open visual studio code, the output says this:

```
2023-12-25 18:24:28.042 [warning] Via 'product.json#extensionEnabledApiProposals' extension 'ms-python.python' wants API proposal 'registerIssueDataProvider' but that proposal DOES NOT EXIST. Likely, the proposal has been finalized (check 'vscode.d.ts') or was abandoned.

2023-12-25 18:24:28.642 [info] Started local extension host with pid 12688.

2023-12-25 18:24:31.323 [info] [perf] Render performance baseline is 82ms
```

When I go to extensions, and try to install python, an error message pops up: `Error while installing 'Python' extension. Please check the [log](command:workbench.action.showWindowLog) for more details.`

The log shows:

```
2023-12-25 18:26:50.925 [error] Error: XHR failed

    at k.onerror (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/mtzbi/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:95:2027)

2023-12-25 18:26:50.977 [error] Error: XHR failed

    at k.onerror (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/mtzbi/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:95:2027)

2023-12-25 18:26:50.984 [error] XHR failed: Error: XHR failed

    at k.onerror (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/mtzbi/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:95:2027)
```

Also when I try to open Edx Harvard CS50 code space on VS code desktop, it says: `"installing extension github code spaces"`, followed by XHR error. The log shows:

```
2023-12-25 18:28:51.685 [error] XHR failed: Error: XHR failed

    at k.onerror (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/mtzbi/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:95:2027)
```

I have re-installed VS code multiple times, let it through my firewall, used "code --ignore-certificate-errors", made sure 'http proxy' is set up correctly, and tried all 4 options in proxy support. But noting is working.

Comment: The error message "XHR failed" usually indicates a problem with network connectivity. You have to check your internet connection.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. My internet connection is fine. Could there be any issue with VS code?

Comment: Could you please try disabling your antivirus software temporarily and download again?

Comment: Unfortunately, it still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This has been reported on the official issue tracker at [Warn: RegisterIssueDataProvider error everywhere #22636](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/22636). Just sit tight and wait for the fix (might take a while since it's holiday season). I'm pretty sure things should keep working fine even though you're getting this warning. As for not being able to install extensions, I wonder if you can still do it via commandline (see [How to install Visual Studio Code extensions from Command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34286515/11107541)).

As for the cause, this is the warning VS Code gives when an extension is published that does something like trying to use an API that was proposed but is now stabilized. I've seen this happen multiple times before (Ex. [extension 'ms-vscode.vscode-selfhost-test-provider' wants API proposal 'testContinuousRun' but that proposal DOES NOT EXIST](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75977433/11107541) and [VS Code does not recognize file extensions. Can't install any extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75447496/11107541)). Though in this particular case, it's weird because it seems like [the PR that adds the usage of that API](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/pull/22500) hasn't even been merged yet. We'll see what the maintainers have to say.

Answer (score 0):

- In VS Code, go to the Extensions view (Ctrl+Shift+X)
- Search for 'Python'
- Locate the Python extension and click on the gear icon next to it
- Select 'Check for Updates' - this will ensure you have the latest
  version of the Python extension.

Once updated, restart VS Code

Check for Stable Internet connection and firewall.

- Disconnect and reconnect to your wifi or ethernet
- Run a speedtest to confirm you have a stable connection
- Try accessing the VS Code marketplace from a web browser at
  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com to see if it loads properly
- Restart your computer and launch VS Code again to force a fresh
  connection

Try installing or updating extensions again, including the Python extension

Comment: I don't see 'Check for Updates' anywhere