# VS Code Extensions are not installing (tried VSIX installation also)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am currently working in angular so I wanted to download some extension of angular but it's not installing in my VS Code. I reinstalled it and I tried to install it in the VSIX method showing errors like

EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'c:\Users\Username.vscode\extensions.a84304b9-25cc-46cf-97f2-c8c3dd1782f2' -> 'c:\Users\Username.vscode\extensions\angular.ng-template-17.0.3'

Unable to download VS Extension even though I tried to reinstall My VS code used the VSIX method.

Comment: Try installing via command line and see what happens.

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77738228/11107541